# L’Amérique ou les Amériques ?

Tags: orthographe, pluriel, noms, noms-propres

J'ai récemment lu "Les Amériques".

Mais `Amérique` étant (à ma connaissance) un nom propre je me suis demandé pourquoi prenait-il ici la marque au pluriel. La signification est-elle différente ?

Comment: Il y a aussi la Flandre et les Flandres.

Comment: ... et l'Ardenne et les Ardennes !

Answer (score 2):

Aujourd'hui les Amériques est le terme utilisé pour se référer de manière non ambiguë à l'Amérique du Sud, l'Amérique du Nord et l'Amérique centrale. En effet, en français dire l'Amérique peut faire référence aux États-Unis d'Amérique ou au continent.

La confusion existe également dans d'autres langues.

*Edit : voir les commentaires à propos de l'Amérique du Nord et de l'Amérique centrale.*

Comment: "Les Amériques" inclut aussi bien sûr l'Amérique centrale.

Comment: Effectivement. Je pensais l'expression en anglais où "North America" inclut l'Amérique du nord et l'Amérique centrale. Je corrige de ce pas

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse, malgré cette dernière cela reste confus à mes yeux. Par exemple lors de l'utilisation de *Je vais en Amérique.* est-il possible de savoir grammaticalement de quelle partie de l'Amérique il s'agit ?

Comment: Impossible de savoir dans quel pays ou dans quelle partie du continent vous vous rendez avec simplement cette phrase